# Output data with no column headings using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to output data from PowerShell without any column headings. I know I can hide the column heading using `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`, but that leaves a blank line at the top.

Here is my example:

```
get-qadgroupmember 'Domain Admins' | Select Name | ft -hide | out-file Admins.txt
```

How do I eliminate the column heading and the blank line?

I could add another line and do this:

```
Get-Content Admins.txt | Where {$_ -ne ""} | out-file Admins1.txt
```

But can I do this on one line?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In your case, when you just select a single property, the easiest way is probably to bypass any formatting altogether:

```
get-qadgroupmember 'Domain Admins' | foreach { $_.Name }
```

This will get you a simple `string[]` without column headings or empty lines. The `Format-*` cmdlets are mainly for human consumption and thus their output is not designed to be easily machine-readable or -parseable.

For multiple properties I'd probably go with the `-f` format operator. Something along the lines of

```
alias | %{ "{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-60}" -f $_.COmmandType,$_.Name,$_.Definition }
```

which isn't pretty but gives you easy and complete control over the output formatting. And no empty lines :-)

Comment: Perfect thanks.  Btw, what's the "{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-60}" doing in your example?

Comment: That's a format string. Usually format strings consist of something in braces. First a numeric index which refers to which item of the object array to format is to be substituted there, you can give a width after the comma. Negative forces left alignment instead of right alignment. Above example will output the command type, the name and the definition of an alias in columns of 10, 10 and 60 characters respectively. It all makes sense once you understand how format strings work :-) (reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

Comment: @Joey, your answer answered so many questions for me... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 59):

A better answer is to leave your script as it was. When doing the `Select name`, follow it by `-ExpandProperty Name` like so:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Admins' | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | out-file Admins.txt
```

Comment: Still ends up with empty lines.

Comment: `Select -ExpandProperty Name` is sufficient, you don't have repeat `Name` twice in the command

Comment: @doubleDown: in this particular example yes but for not in general, for instance I'm using it to retrieve XML attribute named `description`, then, with `$xml` variable containing the content of my XML file I call `$xml.projectMetadata.projectInformation | Select description -ExpandProperty Name`.

Answer (score 44):

If you use "format-table" you can use `-hidetableheaders`

Comment: Please note the problem is NOT about hiding the headers, but about the blank lines produced WHEN you're already hiding the headers with `-hidetableheaders`

Comment: Please note this will hide the headers as requested, AND remove any blank lines:
    (get-qadgroupmember 'Domain Admins' | Select Name | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String).trim()

Comment: Thanks @ScriptMonkey! Your solution with `.trim()` in the comments resulted in my **$winProductName** string returning `Windows 10 Home` which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 12):

add the parameter -expandproperty after the select-object, it will return only data without header.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's the simplest AND the most correct.

Comment: -ExpandProperty worked perfectly. E.g., `pwd | select -ExpandProperty Path`

Answer (score 9):

The -expandproperty does not work with more than 1 object. You can use this one :

```
Select-Object Name | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

If there is more than one value then :

```
Select-Object Name, Country | ForEach-Object {$_.Name + " " + $Country}
```

Comment: You could just use `Select-Object | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}`

Answer (score 3):

Joey mentioned that `Format-*` is for human consumption. If you're writing to a file for machine consumption, maybe you want to use `Export-*`? Some good ones are

- `Export-Csv` - Comma separated value. Great for when you know what the columns are going to be
- `Export-Clixml` - You can export whole objects and collections. This is great for serialization.

If you want to read back in, you can use `Import-Csv` and `Import-Clixml`. I find that I like this better than inventing my own data formats (also it's pretty easy to whip up an `Import-Ini` if that's your preference).

Answer (score 2):

First we grab the command output, then wrap it and select one of its properties. There is only one and its "Name" which is what we want.  So we select the groups property with ".name" then output it.

to text file

```
 (Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Admins' |Select name).name | out-file Admins1.txt
```

to csv

```
(Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Admins' |Select name).name | export-csv -notypeinformation "Admins1.csv"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$server = ('*')+(Read-Host -prompt "What Server Context?")+'*'
$Report = (Get-adcomputer -SearchBase "OU=serverou,DC=domain,DC=com" -filter {name -like $server} -SearchScope Subtree|select Name |Sort -Unique Name) 
$report.Name | Out-File .\output\out.txt -Encoding ascii -Force
$Report
start notepad .\output\out.txt
```

Put **your** server SearchBase in above.
If you are *not sure* what your server OU is try this function below...

```
#Function Get-OSCComputerOU($Computername)

{
    $Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$ComputerName))"

    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = $Filter
    $SearcherPath = $DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
    $DistinguishedName = $SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName

    $OUName = ($DistinguishedName.Split(","))[1]
    $OUMainName = $OUName.SubString($OUName.IndexOf("=")+1)
    
#    $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"ComputerName" = $ComputerName
#                                                     "BelongsToOU" = $OUMainName
#                                                     "Full" = $DistinguishedName}
    $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"Full" = $DistinguishedName}


    $Obj
}
```

Makes sure to run the `Get-OSCComputerOU Servername` with a `select -expandproperty Full` filter.
Then just plug in the response to the Searchbase...

*All thanks to http://www.jaapbrasser.com*