# How to fetch an attribute value from xml using powershell?

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

I have a list of XML files, from which I have to get the string after a particular line.

In the files, I need to look for a tag `Event` and get the attribute value `DLLRoutine`.
e.g. the tag would look something like below ...

```
<Event Definition="Validate" DLLPath="" DLLName="Helper.dll" DLLClass="HelpMain" 
       DLLRoutine="pgFeatureInfoOnValidate_WriteToRegSelectedFeatures" 
       InputParameters="pTreeViewFeatureTreeServerOS" RunOnce="no"/>
```

I just need to get `Dllroutine` values. How to do it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming your XML structure is something similar to:

```
$xml = [xml]'
<Events>
<Event Definition="Validate" DLLPath="" DLLName="Helper.dll" DLLClass="HelpMain" DLLRoutine="pgFeatureInfoOnValidate_WriteToRegSelectedFeatures" InputParameters="pTreeViewFeatureTreeServerOS" RunOnce="no"/>
<Event Definition="Validate1" DLLPath="" DLLName="Helper.dll1" DLLClass="HelpMain1" DLLRoutine="pgFeatureInfoOnValidate_WriteToRegSelectedFeatures" InputParameters="pTreeViewFeatureTreeServerOS" RunOnce="no"/>
</Events>
'

#Or get it from a XML file
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $XMLPath)

$xml.Events.Event | Select DLLName
```

Comment: Great, in addition, I use ` -ExpandProperty Name` to get only value, without headings: `$xml.Events.Event | Select DLLName -ExpandProperty Name`, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184592/11159476

Comment: @gluttony For the select you need to specify the property only once: "| Select -ExpandProperty DLLName"

Answer (score 22):

Assuming your `Event` element has an `Events` element root:

```
$xml.Events.Event.DLLName
```

I've only tested this in Powershell 3

Answer (score 19):

you can use also xpath instead of dot notation:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//Events/Event') | select DLLName
```

Comment: This approach worked really good when trying to parse nodes with special characters on the name.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Select-XML`:

```
$xml = [xml]'
<Events>
<Event Definition="Validate" DLLPath="" DLLName="Helper.dll" DLLClass="HelpMain" DLLRoutine="pgFeatureInfoOnValidate_WriteToRegSelectedFeatures" InputParameters="pTreeViewFeatureTreeServerOS" RunOnce="no"/>
<Event Definition="Validate1" DLLPath="" DLLName="Helper.dll1" DLLClass="HelpMain1" DLLRoutine="pgFeatureInfoOnValidate_WriteToRegSelectedFeatures" InputParameters="pTreeViewFeatureTreeServerOS" RunOnce="no"/>
</Events>
'

Select-XML -xml $xml -xpath "//Event/@DLLName"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$xml.Events.Event.DLLName`

It will work in version 2, I have tried to use xpath in several scripts and it fails every time so until I tried the dot notation I thought I was doing it wrong.