# XML attribute similar to powershell keyword (count)

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

I have an attribute "Count" in my xml , and when I am trying to access the values of the attribute it giving the count of the array

```
$Count = $xml.Para.Lic.Counter.Count
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212452/how-to-fetch-an-attribute-value-from-xml-using-powershell

Comment: @Jay Buckman:Actually I am trying the same way  $Count = $xml.Para.Lic.Counter I select Count , but still its giving the count of array not values

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes around names:

```
$Count = $xml.Para.Lic.Counter.'Count'
```

However, if 'Counter' is an array, you need to access an instance to get the attribute value:

```
    $Count = $xml.Para.Lic.Counter[0].Count
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I am still not able to fetch the values , its still taking count

Comment: taking count of what?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work.  Maybe there is something else wrong with your XML?

```
$xml = Get-Content test.xml      
$xml.catalog.counter.Count
$xml.catalog.counter.'Count'
```

Loading the following test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <counter count="150">
    </counter>
</catalog>
```