# Search XML attribute value using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to fetch an xml attribute value using powershell but not sure how to read the attributes.

Here is my sample xml file with name *myfile.xml*

```
<MyFile>
<Parameter name ="internet" enabled ="true" />
</MyFile>
```

Please suggest me how to fetch the value of attribute *enabled* using powershell.

Comment: possible dupplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212452/how-to-fetch-an-attribute-value-from-xml-using-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution.

You read from the file, cast it as **XML object** and then reference properties via *dot notation*.

```powershell
$XMLPath = "ENTER_YOUR_FILE_PATH"

# Read the file content, cast it as an XML object and store in variable
$xmlfile = [xml](Get-Content $XMLPath)

# Access particular attribute value
$xmlfile.MyFile.Parameter.enabled
```

Output

```powershell
true
```

Additional methods are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12212452/8568965).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Also can you suggest for below
<My File>
<Parameter name ="internet" enabled ="true" />
<Parameter name ="wifi" enabled ="true" />
</My File>

Now i want to get the value of "enabled" based upon attribute "name"

Comment: In order to access conditional attribute values by iteration, you can use **Where-Object** and **ForEach-Object**. For printing the value of _enabled_ for _"internet"_ , the statement goes something like: `$xmlfile.MyFile.Parameter | Where-Object name -eq 'internet' | ForEach-Object { $_.enabled }`