# VB .NET - How to check if 'File and Printer Sharing' is enabled

Tags: vb.net, vpn

I have written a VB .Net front-end to the office SQL server.  I want to expand this so users can access the server via a VPN.  When testing the process, I can only see the SQL server via the VPN if I also have 'File and Printer Sharing' enabled on each client PC, so I want some code to check that both the VPN and the sharing are enabled before trying to access the server.  I have the following three lines which checks that the VPN is running:

```
    Dim myInterfaceList As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    Dim myVPNRunning As Boolean = myInterfaceList.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Name = "MyTestVPN")
    If myVPNRunning Then chkProgress3.Checked = True
```

but I can't find a way (in VB .NET) to check if the client PC has 'File and Printer Sharing' enabled.  I have found this article [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787845/file-and-printer-sharing-status) which discusses using Powershell to check, but I don't know how to translate this into VB .Net code (or even if this is the correct / best way).  The office network is not a Domain, so I can't enable sharing through Group Policy.

Has anyone else tackled this?
Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Rather than providing direct access to the database you may consider creating an API (ie: middleware) which authenticates the users and handles the database communication.

Comment: For getting info using PowerShell, the following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72651882/10024425

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File and Printer Sharing Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787845/file-and-printer-sharing-status)

Comment: Thanks user9938, but I think that an API is overkill for my requirements.  Just wanted to check the VPN was active before I tried to use it.  Thanks anyway, may have a look down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows how to check if File and Printer sharing is enabled using PowerShell in VB.NET.

**Download/install NuGet package for PowerShell**

- `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies` (.NET Framework)
- `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` (.NET 6)

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/10024425) for more information.

---

**Add the following Imports statements**:

- `Imports System.Management.Automation`

**IsFileAndPrinterSharingEnabled**:

```
Private Function IsFileAndPrinterSharingEnabled() As Boolean
    Using ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
        Dim result As String = ps.AddScript("Get-NetAdapterBinding | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks' -and $_.Name -eq 'ethernet'} | Select -ExpandProperty Enabled").Invoke()(0).ToString()
        'Dim result As String = ps.AddScript("Get-NetAdapterBinding | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks' -and $_.Name -eq 'ethernet'} | ForEach-Object {$_.Enabled}").Invoke()(0).ToString()

        If result = "True" Then
            Return True
        End If
    End Using

    Return False
End Function
```

**Resources**:

- [File and Printer Sharing Status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788254/10024425)
- [Output data with no column headings using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408042/output-data-with-no-column-headings-using-powershell)

**Other Resources**

- [Can't access my SQL Server via C# form application from client device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425)
- [SMB: File and printer sharing ports should be open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/best-practices-analyzer/smb-open-file-sharing-ports)
- [How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-And-disable-smbv1-v2-v3)

Comment: What would the purpose of the commented-out line `'Dim result As String = ...` be?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: A slightly different command that one can use adapted from [Output data with no column headings using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408042/output-data-with-no-column-headings-using-powershell).